# JS Img tag Creating "" before the src

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code for generating a image with a hyperlink attached to it, using a var instead of the straight lane and idk why but its breaking the img tag with "" before the src=" link

this is my code

```js
var timeline_image = timelines[i].image 
  ? `<div class="image"> 
    <a href="`+timelines[i].urlir +`"
      <img src="`+timelines[i].image+`"/>
    </a>
  </div>` 
  : '';
```

and its breaking without showing the image, when checking the element on the browser is showing this result :

```html
    <a href="www.wikipedia.org" <img="" src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/59a706d4f5e2319b70240ef9/1625681979705-ARY96NYTFGYJDSNG3OLT/n9n5KDd.jpg?format=600w"></a>
```

i really don't know whats wrong or how to avoid that

Comment: You're not closing the a tag with a ">". Proper indentation goes a long way in helping find syntax issues.

Comment: i closed the tag with </img> didnt work 
also i wrote the code without the variables and went thru..

Comment: He means closing the opening anchor tag - this is the corrected version: `var timeline_image  = timelines[i].image ? '<div class="image"> <a href="'+timelines[i].urlir +'"><img src="'+timelines[i].image+'"/></a></div>' : '';`

Comment: just tried that @CharlesBamford and didnt work, even adding " still the same

Comment: You're using template literals, why on earth are you still using string concatenation? That's _literally_ what template literals solve: ```const blah = `<div class="image"><a href="${timelines[i].urlir}"><img src="${timelines[i].image}"/></a></div>`;```, you don't break out of a template literal, you use `${...}` to directly put data in your string so you don't run into problems _exactly_ like this =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Looks like he's using the template literal just so he can split it over multiple lines, not for its more important feature.